# Kotlin short circuit map{}.firstOrNull{}

Tags: kotlin

I need to map a list and retrieve the first non null element, and I need the map operation to be short circuited like it should be in Java 8 streams API. Is there a ready way to do this in Kotlin, without Java 8 streams?

I created my own extension method to do this:

```
fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.firstNonNullMapping(transform: (T) -> R?): R? {
    for (element in this) {
        val result = transform(element)
        if (result != null) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

A test proves that this works

```
val firstNonNullMapping = listOf(null, 'a', 'b')
        .firstNonNullMapping {
            assertNotEquals(it, 'b') // Mapping should be stopped before reaching 'b'
            it
        }
assertEquals(firstNonNullMapping, 'a')
```

IntelliJ, however, suggest that I replace my for loop with the much neater

```
return this
        .map { transform(it) }
        .firstOrNull { it != null }
```

Problem is that this will map all elements of the iterable, and it is essential to my use case that is stops at the first non null element.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kotlin has lazily evaluated [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/) that correspond to Java 8 streams, instead of invoking `stream()` on a collection, you invoke `asSequence()`:

```
return this
        .asSequence()
        .mapNotNull { transform(it) }
        .firstOrNull()
```

Comment: `.firstOrNull { it != null }` is not the same as `firstOrNull()`. The first will return the first non-null element, or null if the sequence is empty. The latter will return the first element regardless of whether it's null or not (or null if it's empty).

Comment: Alternatively, use `this.asSequence().mapNotNull { transform(it) }.firstOrNull()`

Comment: Avoiding it != null can be with: .mapNotNull { ... }.firstOrNull()

Comment: I've edited the answer with the above suggestion

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin 1.5 provides a shortcut replacement for the combination of
`.asSequence()`, `.mapNotNull { ... }` and `.first/firstOrNull()`: the functions  [`firstNotNullOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of.html) and [`firstNotNullOfOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of-or-null.html) respectively.

They execute the `transform` function once for each element and stop as soon as they encounter the first non-null result of that function, so they are short-circuiting.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work and this one is actually up to date. Therefore, this one should be the accepted one, now.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what is faster, the @ingoKegel's solution, or this:

```
return this.firstOrNull { transform(it) != null }?.let { transform(it) }
```

Comment: Depending on the transformation this could give much overhead. But for my case I need the transformation to only execute once

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin 1.5 introduced the collection method firstNotNullOfOrNull that is implemented basically exactly how your own extension method does it.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of-or-null.html

I'm guessing IntelliJ would be happy about this.